# Logging requests of HLS stream segment in connected iOS Safari

Tags: ios, html, audio, safari, http-live-streaming

I am trying to debug my web based HLS player (with HTML5  tag) and would like to monitor the network request to fetch the segments of the stream. This works fine in all desktop browsers (safari, chrome, firefox), and works with the OSX Safari, as well.

But when I connect to a iOS Safari (Simulator or real iPhone), only the request of the m3u-file shows up in the network monitor, not the requests to the segments of the stream.

Is there a way to monitor those requests on iOS Safari?

The reason I want to do this is trying to avoid automatic loading of segments while the player is paused/stopped. This works fine with hls.js, but I am not sure how iOS Safari handles the preload=none attribute. Although [here Apple says that "Safari on iOS never preloads"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AudioandVideoTagBasics/AudioandVideoTagBasics.html), this does not seem to be true when pausing the player. (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement/1633059-preload, too)

Thanks!

P.S.: I tried to get any information in Apple's forums before, unfortunately without any success (https://discussions.apple.com/message/32027089#32027089).

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor these requests like any other. I recommend Fiddler... It works as a proxy server and can be used to monitor or edit traffic, even with HTTPS. For lower level debugging or cases where you can't use a proxy, use a packet sniffer like Wireshark.

Comment: Ok, thank you. So there is no way to do this via connected Browser, correct? I need to install some proxy thing, be it wireshark, Fiddler, Charles, etc.

Comment: @PaulWellnerBou If there is, I don't know of a way.  I only messed with the iOS development tools for a bit, several years ago.  Perhaps someone can give you a more specific answer, but using more the more generic tools will definitely work if you can't get your iOS tools to capture what you want.

Comment: I used to use Charles for debugging HLS on iOS all the time, but nowadays it just fails. I suspect ATS, even tho my app has 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' set in Info.